# How to create tab-section similar to web browser tabs in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

Please do help me out in creating a tab-section similar to web-browser tab so that when I open a page it has to opened in the tab format, and at the same time operations like closing, drag and dropping the tab should be present.

Suggest me any libraries that are present to solve this problem.

Comment: What about react-draggable-tab, could you please check it I would like to get the similar one. But there are few errors in it. So please try it suggest me to how to use react-draggable-tab.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, I believe this is what you need:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable-tabs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Tabs from "react-draggable-tabs";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.moveTab = this.moveTab.bind(this);
    this.selectTab = this.selectTab.bind(this);
    this.closedTab = this.closedTab.bind(this);
    this.addTab = this.addTab.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      tabs: [
        {
          id: 1,
          content: "Cute Cat",
          active: true,
          display: (
            <img
              src="http://memecrunch.com/meme/RFHY/cute-cat/image.png"
              alt="cute cat"
              width="500px"
            />
          )
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          content: (
            <span>
              <i className="fa fa-paw" aria-hidden="true" /> Cute Dog
            </span>
          ),
          display: (
            <img
              src="http://slappedham.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Cute-White-Dog.jpg"
              alt="cute dog"
              width="500px"
            />
          )
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          content: "Cute Duck",
          display: (
            <iframe
              title="DuckDuckGo"
              src="https://duckduckgo.com/"
              style={{
                border: "0",
                margin: "50px",
                width: "500px",
                height: "800px"
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  moveTab(dragIndex, hoverIndex) {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      let newTabs = [...state.tabs]
      newTabs.splice(hoverIndex, 0, newTabs.splice(dragIndex, 1)[0]);

      return { tabs: newTabs };
    });
  }

  selectTab(selectedIndex, selectedID) {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      const newTabs = state.tabs.map(tab => ({
        ...tab,
        active: tab.id === selectedID
      }));
      return { tabs: newTabs };
    });
  }

  closedTab(removedIndex, removedID) {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      let newTabs = [...state.tabs];
      newTabs.splice(removedIndex, 1);

      if (state.tabs[removedIndex].active && newTabs.length !== 0) {
        // automatically select another tab if needed
        const newActive = removedIndex === 0 ? 0 : removedIndex - 1;
        newTabs[newActive].active = true;
      }

      return { tabs: newTabs };
    });
  }

  addTab() {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      let newTabs = [...state.tabs];
      newTabs.push({
        id: newTabs.length + 1,
        content: "Cute *",
        display: <div key={newTabs.length + 1}>Cute *</div>
      });

      return { tabs: newTabs };
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const activeTab = this.state.tabs.filter(tab => tab.active === true);
    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs
          moveTab={this.moveTab}
          selectTab={this.selectTab}
          closeTab={this.closedTab}
          tabs={this.state.tabs}
        >
          <button onClick={this.addTab}>+</button>
        </Tabs>
        {activeTab.length !== 0 ? activeTab[0].display : ""}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Live demo of the library:
https://codesandbox.io/s/n0952xxo6p